# Run second grep on each string returned by first grep

Tags: shell, grep, cut

I have two files `file1` and `file2` and a pattern `pattern`.

Using grep on `pattern` in `file1` and `cut`, I generate some strings like following:

```
String1
String2
String3
String4
String5
```

For each of these strings, I have to grep file2. How can I do that?

For now, I am doing this manually, but a better method must exist. I can probably do this using a for loop, but I wonder if just piping the results of first `grep` and `cut` to second `grep` can work anyhow.

Note:
Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: Please provide working samples of `file1`, `file2` and `pattern` along with expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) with `-f` option:

```
grep -Ff <(grep -o 'pattern' file1) file2
```

Comment: short and sweet. Nice.

Comment: Ah, the OP is using bash? The question didn't mention that. How did you know?!

Comment: As educators, then, we have the opportunity to correct that misapprehension.